# after previous `counsel-yank-pop`, `yank` the last yanked entry

Tags: yank, ivy, counsel

**short**: after a `counsel-yank-pop`, `yank` does not yank the same entry. How can I achieve that behavior?

**long**: Having a kill-ring like:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

When doing a `C-y` (`yank`) and `M-y` (`yank-pop`) 'bar' will be inserted. And for every repeated `C-y`, 'bar' will be inserted again.
This is the behavior (repeated insertion of 'bar') I'd like to have with `counsel-yank-pop` instead of `yank-pop`.
But `counsel-yank-pop` does not seem to modify the kill-ring pointer for `yank`.
How can I achieve the wanted behavior?

**Note**: I'd like to keep using `ivy` and `counsel`, instead of switching to `helm` or something else.

Comment: This and other behaviours and intricacies of `yank-pop` are not currently supported by `counsel-yank-pop` (though someone may well be able to hack around the status quo). In the meantime I have submitted [PR #1356](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/pull/1356) to address this as well as many other potential discrepancies between `counsel-yank-pop` and `yank-pop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`counsel-yank-pop` works as desired as of [2017-12-08](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/commit/50aa561b63b0c481324e371cb100b30c871dfea3).

The command now also accepts the same prefix argument as `yank-pop` which causes the corresponding kill to be preselected during completion.

Finally, `counsel-yank-pop` improves upon `yank-pop` in that it does not require the `last-command` to be a `yank`. In such cases it just inserts the selected kill at point without replacing any previous yanks.

Comment: yes, this version is now on melpa and it is working, many thanks!