# how to move `consult-yank-pop` selected entry to top of kill ring after selection?

Tags: yank, consult

I'm using the package `consult`, so after I press <kbd>M-y</kbd> (`consult-yank-pop`) without pressing <kbd>C-y</kbd> (`yank`) first, I get a list for me to choose. Say, I get the list in the kill ring as

- a
- b
- c
- d

If I navigate to "c" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get "c" inserted. However, if I want to insert the "c" entry immediately again, I will still need to navigate to "c".

I'm not sure if this is the intended way of doing this. Is it possible that after I select the "c" entry, somehow I can move it to (or near) the top of the kill ring? Many thanks!

(It seems that [`counsel-yank-pop`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37395/) is doing this, but I do not how to make the appropriate adjustment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your value of `consult-yank-rotate` non-nil? When this variable is non-nil the yanked value should be at the top of the kill ring on the next yank.

Comment: WOW! Although I just get into the package recently, I really should have tried to update everything first.